# Verificación de mi e-mail como nuevo usuario de este sitio

Tags: discussion

Mi pregunta es si es correcto al aceptar el enlace (ham.stackexchange) eso aparece en la barra de direcciones y al seleccionar tal dirección se mira un enlace muy diferente con muchas letras....es normal?? Quisiera saber si aún continuó con errores en mis busquedas......

No entiendo que está pasando...no entiendo como yergue a este sitio...creo k mi desesperación no me deja pensar...temo no estar cumpliendo con las políticas del sitio o algo así...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you want to participate in the site, you will have to write in English. If you can [edit your question](http://meta.ham.stackexchange.com/posts/270/edit) into English, it will help us answer your concern.

Comment: Pieces decir en que página se occure? -- Can you tell us what page this happens on?

Answer (score 1):

Translated using a well-known-search-engine:

> My question is whether it is right to accept the link
>   (ham.stackexchange) that appears in the address bar and selecting such
>   link address a very different look with many letters .... is normal ??
>   I wonder if he still continued mistakes in my searches ......
>
> I do not understand what's going on ... do not understand how this
>   place stands ... I think my despair k not let me think ... I fear not
>   being in compliance with the site's policies or something ...

Some websites use GUID characters in the URL which is visible in the address bar of your browser, that might explain a "different looking link address"

**Help us to help you**, please try to explain in more detail:

- what URL are you visiting ?
- what do you see exactly in the address bar ?
- any other information you may share to help us help you ?

Tip: Please post in English, use a translator-web-page if you have too,

HTH, Edwin.